# (centos & ubuntu) both saves 8021X password in plain text

Tags: networking, ubuntu, centos-7

(centos 7 & ubuntu 16) both saves 8021X password in plain text

anyway to hash them, etc?

centos:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/keys-eno1
```

ubuntu:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired-Connection-1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a section of the Arch Wiki's NetworkManager section that details encrypted stored wifi passwords using Gnome-keyring or KDE Wallet. You can find it below:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Encrypted_Wi-Fi_passwords